# How to use scrypt in php shared hosting

Tags: php, hash, passwords, scrypt

I am just learning php I want to use scrypt for password hashing but according to this website:
https://scott.arciszewski.me/blog/2013/10/php-scrypt-setup

I need to have root privilege in the webserver to use scrypt. But we don't have direct access to the webserver since it is a shared hosting. I want to use scrypt. Thanks in advance.